# Do Gunslinger firearms count as ranged weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, fighting-style, firearms, gunslinger

Do Firearms (specifically, the firearms from Critical Role's [Gunslinger Martial Archetype for Fighters](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/170778/Gunslinger-Martial-Archetype-for-Fighters)) count as ranged weapons?

Can they be used with the Archery or Close Quarters Shooter (UA) fighting styles?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Firearms are ranged weapons

From the [gunslinger on DnD Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/subclasses/gunslinger), under firearm properties, the last sentence reads:

> Firearms are ranged weapons.

This means that they work with anything that requires a ranged weapon, including the Archery and Close Quarters Shooter fighting styles.